# Layout copyright

Tags: layout

My website has a layout very similar to that of Twitter's when one is logged in. However, all of the images, content, and code is written by myself not looking at twitter's source.

My site has a black bar on top that mirrors twitters visually, almost identically, although images/text is different.

My site has a bottom content area split up into two parts like twitter's. One section is for questions, while the other section slides out when a question is clicked on, like twitter. However again, colors, content, images, and site purpose are 100% different.

Basically, I thought twitter's design was really cool, so I implemented it in my own site. Nevertheless, I will do anything to avoid any type of lawsuit with twitter, so is the layout I described above a candidate for copyright infringement and could I be ordered to shut down my site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't give a legal opinion - IANAL, and have not seen your site.

The layout you describe is not, from my recollection anyway, unique to twitter - there are only so many header / footer / columns permutations that are useful - so is pretty rare to find a truly unique one.

The discriminating question that I would ask myself:
"If I was in the other position, could I fairly think my design had been ripped off?" and don't BS yourself when answering.

If you can honestly answer no to that question, have not used their graphics, and have not made it a pixel perfect layout clone, then you should be alright.

Along the lines of what Jhourlad said so well, if it really feels wrong, that will come out in your answer to the question above.

It sounds to me like you have thought about it along the way - it's ok to be inspired by the work of others, good design involves building upon what has come before.

Answer (score 2):

Well, legality aside, if you feel guilty about something, don't do it. Man's conscience has a built-in mechanism of triggering one's internal alarms when he knows (but can't accept) the fact that he did something against his own moral or ethical standards (or both), in your case. Breaking the law also has the same effect.

I was actually thinking you're much more worried about the first two.

Comment: I'm just not sure if I am overreacting.

Comment: Don't worry, you're not. Those things have always been one of the  major considerations among developers. Good luck on your project though.

Comment: I certainly do NOT condone ripping off other graphic designer's work...but in this case it sounds like this was closer to "inspiration" than "copying" (i hope).  That said, i absolutely agree with @Jhourlad that if you think you have done something wrong...maybe you have.